# How to get mel-spectagram peaks array in python?

Tags: python, audio, audio-fingerprinting

I want to make an audio fingerprint, so i need to get a spectrogram peaks array. I've tried to find solution in the internet, but there's nothing.

Here is the spectagram example

```
import librosa, librosa.display
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import IPython.display as ipd
from FFT import FFT

def MEL_SPECTOGRAM(signal, sr, fileName):
    ipd.Audio(signal, rate=sr)
    # this is the number of samples in a window per fft
    n_fft = 2048
    # The amount of samples we are shifting after each fft
    hop_length = 512

    audio_stft = librosa.core.stft(signal, hop_length=hop_length, n_fft=n_fft)
    spectrogram = np.abs(audio_stft)
    log_spectro = librosa.amplitude_to_db(spectrogram)

    librosa.util.normalize(log_spectro)

    librosa.display.specshow(log_spectro, sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length, cmap='magma', win_length=n_fft)

    plt.plot()
    plt.show()
```

[mel-spectagram example]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0zKd.png)

### The best solution i found was this video, but unfortunately, it was written on wolfram, so i can't use it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCHeGesfJe8&ab_channel=Wolfram

---

Comment: Your code says "mel spectrogram", but what is shown creates a STFT/linear spectrogram

Answer (score 0):

Peak finding in a 2d array is a common operation in computer-vision. So a good way to do this in Python is to lean on a computer vision like `scipy.ndimage`.

One of the best resources for explaining the landmark/constellation approach to audio fingerprinting (as used by Shazam et.c.) can be found in [Fundamentals of Audio Processing: Chapter 7, Audio Identification notebook](https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/resources/MIR/FMP/C7/C7S1_AudioIdentification.html). It contains Python code for computing the constellation map, in the function `compute_constellation_map`.

Below is complete, runnable code based on the above resource.
I have only made a few fixes for compatibility with modern librosa.

```py
import librosa
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

def compute_spectrogram(fn_wav, Fs=22050, N=2048, H=1024, bin_max=128, frame_max=None):
    x, Fs = librosa.load(fn_wav, sr=Fs)
    x_duration = len(x) / Fs
    X = librosa.stft(x, n_fft=N, hop_length=H, win_length=N, window='hamming')
    if bin_max is None:
        bin_max = X.shape[0]
    if frame_max is None:
        frame_max = X.shape[0]
    Y = np.abs(X[:bin_max, :frame_max])
    return Y

def compute_constellation_map(Y, dist_freq=7, dist_time=7, thresh=0.01):
    """Compute constellation map (implementation using image processing)    
    Args:
        Y (np.ndarray): Spectrogram (magnitude)
        dist_freq (int): Neighborhood parameter for frequency direction (kappa) (Default value = 7)
        dist_time (int): Neighborhood parameter for time direction (tau) (Default value = 7)
        thresh (float): Threshold parameter for minimal peak magnitude (Default value = 0.01)

    Returns:
        Cmap (np.ndarray): Boolean mask for peak structure (same size as Y)
    """
    result = scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter(Y, size=[2*dist_freq+1, 2*dist_time+1], mode='constant')
    Cmap = np.logical_and(Y == result, result > thresh)
    return Cmap

path = librosa.example('nutcracker')
spec = compute_spectrogram(path)
Cmap = compute_constellation_map(spec, dist_freq=7, dist_time=3)
print(Cmap.shape)
```

Here is also some plotting code to show the output. Again based on the above notebooks.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_constellation_map(Cmap, Y=None, xlim=None, ylim=None, title='',
                           xlabel='Time (sample)', ylabel='Frequency (bins)',
                           s=5, color='r', marker='o', figsize=(7, 3), dpi=72):
    if Cmap.ndim > 1:
        (K, N) = Cmap.shape
    else:
        K = Cmap.shape[0]
        N = 1
    if Y is None:
        Y = np.zeros((K, N))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi)
    im = ax.imshow(Y, origin='lower', aspect='auto', cmap='gray_r', interpolation='nearest')
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    ax.set_title(title)
    Fs = 1
    if xlim is None:
        xlim = [-0.5/Fs, (N-0.5)/Fs]
    if ylim is None:
        ylim = [-0.5/Fs, (K-0.5)/Fs]
    ax.set_xlim(xlim)
    ax.set_ylim(ylim)
    n, k = np.argwhere(Cmap == 1).T
    ax.scatter(k, n, color=color, s=s, marker=marker)
    plt.tight_layout()
    return fig, ax, im

fig, ax, im = plot_constellation_map(Cmap, np.log(1 + 1 * spec), color='r', s=20, figsize=(15, 5))
fig.savefig('constellation-map.png')
```

Running it should give an image such as this:

[image]